# Joomla - проблемы с установкой.

Tags: установка, joomla, cms

Все знают, что во время установки Joomla! 1.7.2 должна появиться такая стр.
[image]

Но внезапно я получил это:

[image]

Это я на хост пытался закинуть Joomla! Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Установка дальше не пошла у меня.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Битый дистр, перезалейте либо скачайте с другого источника. Если глубже смотреть - покоцан/отсутствует языковой файл инсталляции, но раз так, могли недокачаться и другие, потому совет тот же.

Comment: Самое интересное, что на Денвере все работает! Может на хосте PHP интерпретатор другой?

Comment: Судя по этому комментарию, джумла криво залилась на сервер) Просто удалите ее и попробуйте еще раз. Если  php>=5.0, проблема не в этом.

Comment: 2 раза так делал. Ничего не помогло.

Comment: А блин, так да, хостинг)) На ошибки не обратил внимания. Прочитайте http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=619954 и после заливки проставьте права `0777` на `configuration.php`. Еще спросите у хостера, какого хрена отключена функция `parse_ini_file`. Там еще на некоторое надо права поставить(`/administrator/`, `/components/` и тд), но установка уже должна пройти.

Answer (score 0):

Что- то было подобное, не страшно
Я вроде переустанавливал, попробуй еще разок
а вообще то есть видео уроки делай по ним напр в Ютубе